# Parameter estimation of LMM with multiplicative measurement error in fixed co-variate - How?

Tags: mixed-model, measurement-error

I have a linear mixed model, with multiplicative measurement error on the fixed co-variate only (i.e. the random part is assumed to be measured without error). How could I best estimate the coefficients?

Mathematically, using standard notation, I have

$Y=Z\beta+Ub+\epsilon$

$X=Z\delta$

$\beta$ is the fixed effect, $b$ is the random effect. $Z$ is the unobserved error-free regressor. $X$ is the observed version with multiplicative error.

I am not quite sure what a 'standard' distribution for $\delta$ would be , but I happy to assume it is whatever 'standard' distribution it is. i.e. mean '0' (in the multiplicative sense....) and homoscedasticity.

How do I estimate $\beta$?